# Differentiation between facebook and pinterest og:image

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-opengraph, sharing, pinterest

I have two different image formats for Facebook and for Pinterest. It seems to be that both are using openGraph for the metadata. So both using the same og: image source. 
Is it possible to make a differentiation between Facebook and Pinterest, so that each get its own source and format?

Comment: Look at the useragent of the request to your server. Facebook will say that it is Facebook

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Even if one could target this through the user agent, that information could be faked

Answer (score 1):

You can check the user-agent of the request and display different content.

Facebook user-agent:

```
facebookexternalhit/1.1
```

Pinterest user agent:

```
Pinterest
```

Docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler
- https://help.pinterest.com/en/articles/about-pinterest-crawler-0